# implement dc chart in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i have added dc plugins to my ember app.
in my hbs i have added

here is javascript code:

var data = [

```
        {date: "12/27/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 190, http_302: 100},
        {date: "12/28/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 10, http_302: 100},
        {date: "12/29/2012", http_404: 1, http_200: 300, http_302: 200},
        {date: "12/30/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "12/31/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/01/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/02/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 10, http_302: 1},
        {date: "01/03/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/04/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/05/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/06/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 200, http_302: 1},
        {date: "01/07/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 200, http_302: 100}
        ];
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = Date.parse(d.date);
    d.total= d.http_404+d.http_200+d.http_302;
});

var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});
var hits = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.total;});
var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;

hitslineChart
    .width(500).height(200)
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .group(hits)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
    .yAxisLabel("Hits per day");

dc.renderAll();
```

how to write this javascript code in controller.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should encapsulate the code above inside a component instead.

And put all DOM-related coded inside `didInsertElement` method in the component class.